# Georeference one vector layer using another vector layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, georeferencing, footprint

I'm unsure if this what I'm looking to do is possible...

I have two polygon layers - the orange layer is georeferenced and blue is not. The pink is just a boundary layer (can be ignored). The orange and blue layers are very similar but it would require manually georeferencing to for the blue to be in the same position as orange (moving, rotating, scaling).

What I'm trying to figure out is - it is possible to automatically georeference one polygon layer using another polygon layer? Both layers do share a field with a common ID that would match.

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.2

[image: Sccreenshot:]

Comment: Look at the spatial adustment toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

**Georeferencing** is to spatially manipulate Raster images. Spatial Adjustment is what you're after. Sometimes, reprojections help reference spatial data, but yours looks rotated and not warped.